Python code to download hls stream to mp4
I wrote the following code to download a video from a website. Chrome extensions can detect the video and download it. However, my code gets the following errors. Any help?
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from subprocess import check_output

video_url = 'https://www.dimakids.com/ab6al-aldigetal-s3-1415387355-21011.html#sets'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

url = requests.get(video_url, headers=headers)
page = url.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")

result = str(soup.find_all('video')[0])
result = result.split('src="')[1].split('" type=')[0] 
print(result)

# seg = requests.get(result)
# """
# Error: requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='stream.foupix.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /animeios/1415387355/ab6al_aldigetal_s3_01.mp4/index.m3u8?tkn=jja4Czj-AzbJx1JmvDvQeA&amp;tms=1733079050 (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)')))
# """
# print(seg)


print(check_output(f'ffmpeg -i "{result}" -codec copy file.mp4', shell=True))
"""
Error: https://stream.foupix.com/animeios/1415387355/ab6al_aldigetal_s3_01.mp4/index.m3u8?tkn=SWf7n3qH8MwFLlq18wngIQ&amp;tms=1733079103: Server returned 403 Forbidden (access denied)
"""

The link works as any hls downloader can capture the video and download it as seen here (of course token and timestamp values change everytime it captures the video):
Page URL    https://www.dimakids.com/ab6al-aldigetal-s3-1415387355-21011.html#sets
Thumbnail   https://www.dimakids.com/images/anime/cat_1415387355.jpg
main url    https://stream.foupix.com/animeios/1415387355/ab6al_aldigetal_s3_01.mp4/index.m3u8?tkn=6nyEskSbHBI713sG0uhZJQ&tms=1733171604
video component https://stream.foupix.com/animeios/1415387355/ab6al_aldigetal_s3_01.mp4/index.m3u8?tkn=6nyEskSbHBI713sG0uhZJQ&tms=1733171604

First, appeared requests. Exceptions. SSLError error, usually because the SSL certificate authentication. This may be due to special circumstances in the configuration of the site's SSL certificate, or your request Settings. In this case, you can try to ignore SSL certificate validation by adding the verify=False argument to the requests.get method, like this: url = requests.get(video_url, headers, verify=False)
However, it is important to note that ignoring SSL certificate verification can be a security risk and should only be used if you are sure you understand the risks and are in a test environment. Second, behind the mentioned error of https://stream.foupix.com/anime, because you did not give complete details of the error, not too good accurate judgment. There may be a problem with the video link itself, such as invalid, deleted, or requiring specific permissions to access. Hopefully, this analysis has been helpful, and you can follow the suggestions above to try changing the code and observe the results.

Thank you for your answer. Ignoring certificate verification (by adding verify=False) ended up receiving the same error of ffmpeg command (<Response [403]>). I know the link works, I can open it in the browser, and any hls downloader can capture the video and download it. ffmpeg gives this error ([https @ 000002480ad6aa80] HTTP error 403 Forbidden).
